# Javascript positioning tree node

Tags: javascript, layout, tree, positioning

I need know the position on each node of this tree, I am using javaScript
I am trying but still having problem on overlapping/spacing

[image: a busy cat]
![Family Tree]

I have child list of each node.
A=> C, B, D 
C=> E, F, G
so on.

Please help me.

Comment: 'Position' in terms of `x`,`y` coordinates on the page, or in terms of where it sits on the family tree (child of `X`, parent of `Y`, sibling of `Z`)? What 'position' would you expect for `F` for example?

Comment: consider this 2d grid(R X C). R for row and C for column. R & C will based on tree size. top left is (0, 0) and A is (0,C/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution here( [tree_layout_lw.py](http://new-vistrails.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/core/tree_layout_lw.py) ). Just convert this code to javascript & it's working very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

As you have the structure you mentioned, one idea I can think is:

Let's consider you have a 2D space of X per Y, that is top left corner (0,0), bottom right corner (X,Y)

First you will position A at the coordinates (X/2, 1) that is on the second row, in the middle of the table.

Then, the left child will be at half of horizontal A coordinates, that is ( X/4, 3), and vertically down with 2 cells.
The middle child of A will have ( X/2, 3), the right child of A will have ( 3*X/4, 3).

And accordingly each child will be positioned based on the position of its parent.

Nice problem to solve, if you have smth. developed I'd love to have a look.

Comment: Value of X,Y not fixed. Need to calculate which dimension need for this tree.

Comment: Tree should be positioning like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49962071/temp/f_tree.jpg